# cant create nestjs project

Tags: npm, nestjs, yarnpkg

I am trying to make new nestjs project on my windows10  using the `nest new project-name` command.

However, after while it tells me this error:

> ```
> ? Which package manager would you �� to use? yarn
> ����� Installation in progress... �
> Failed to execute command: yarn install --silent
> ✕ Installation in progress... �
> �  Packages installation failed, see above
> ```

I tried with yarn and got the same error.

I tried `npm cache clean --force` but nothing changes - the same error occurs

Actually that's so annoying. Why should I get this error **after** waiting for 20 minutes? They can check for this error before installation

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. By upgrading the node version the problem was solved. I upgrade my node version to LTS by 'n' node version manager